# Qual é a maneira mais eficiente de fazer com que literais de string não apareçam no código compilado?

Tags: c, desempenho, segurança

Qual é a maneira mais eficiente de fazer com que literais de *string* não apareçam no código compilado? Eu quero impedir a engenharia reversa. Para fazer isso, tentei o seguinte código. No entanto, estou preocupado com o desempenho:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const volatile char a = 'a', s = ' ';
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts((const char[]){a-32, a+17, a+1, a+8, a+19, a+17, a, a+17, a+24, s, a+18, a+19, a+17, a+8, a+13, a+6, s, a+19, a+7, a, a+19, s, a+18, a+7, a+14, a+20, a+11, a+3, s, a+13, a+14, a+19, s, a+18, a+7, a+14, a+22, s, a+8, a+13, s, a+2, a+14, a+12, a+15, a+8, a+11, a+4, a+3, s, a+2, a+14, a+3, a+4, 0});
    return 0;
}
```

Isso deve imprimir uma sequência, e essa sequência nunca é encontrada no executável compilado. Existe mais uma maneira de impedir a engenharia reversa por esses meios? Estou esperando algum tipo de código.

Comment: Já comentei muitas vezes isso aqui no site (vou ver se acho a referência), mas regra básica é: praticamente sempre a preocupação com engenharia reversa é inversamente proporcional à qualidade do produto questionado, então está "protegido pela própria natureza". Compensa guardar energia para o desenvolvimento do produto em si. Quando isso vier a ser um problema real, a própria maturidade tecnológica da pessoa já terá filtrado os problemas essenciais, aí dá para buscar algumas tecnologias mais específicas que nem caberiam no site. O essencial mesmo é o que [já foi respondido aqui](/a/435152/70).

Comment: Daria para "especializar" a pergunta de acordo com a preocupação selecionada. Por exemplo, "como protejo a senha do DB no executavel?" - Não protege, o erro é por no executável. Normalmente nada justifica isso.  "Como faço para não mudarem meus créditos no software?" - ai nao precisa esconder a string, só verificar se houve alteração no código (ainda pode ser crackeado, mas já complica). A pergunta como está e o que chamamos de [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/70)

Comment: Dependendo da natureza e do uso dessa string, você poderia talvez buscá-la em um servidor de sua propriedade, usando login e senha inseridos pelo usuário. Porque hardcodar as credenciais daria no mesmo problema. Se essa não é uma solução viável, talvez uma string que represente tamanha importância no seu executável não seja a solução ideal.

Answer (score 7):

Não colocando no executável. A única forma de impedir que uma *string* não seja pega por qualquer forma de engenharia reversa é ela não existindo. Se precisa do dado em algum momento dentro da aplicação, seja no executável ou não, não estará seguro.

Pode fazer algo para ofuscar ligeiramente, mas não impede engenharia reversa.

Esqueça o desempenho, esse código é mais do que rápido, é impossível fazer um código mais rápido que isso a não ser tirando a aritmética, até porque ele é muito simples, e dá proteção **zero** do conteúdo. Tudo é compromisso (*tradeoff*), não queria ser seguro e rápido ao mesmo tempo, não existe milagre. Não que isso importe nesse caso.

Não tente dar segurança, uma pessoa ingênua tentado fazer isso contra uma pessoa com conhecimento chega ser desleal e mais inseguro do que nem tentar, porque está achando que deu alguma segurança. E se tentar faça do jeito mais simples, não coloque uma informação que não pode ser pega por uma pessoa, ache outro método de conseguir o mesmo. Ou aceite que a informação será acessível. A única segurança real que pode dar aí é não colocar informação sensível no executável. E o que está fazendo é ingênuo, não é seguro.

Ficaria ligeiramente mais seguro se fizesse um algoritmo bem mais complexo, se usasse um algoritmo confiável de criptografia, mas quem sabe obter informação conseguirá do mesmo jeito porque a pessoa consegue ver a execução e principalmente o resultado final descriptografado, limpinho, do jeito que ela precisa saber para acabar com a segurança, ela não precisa nem fazer conta. Esse é um trabalho inócuo, não perca tempo com isso. E não fazendo isso não terá o problema de desempenho.

Vou repetir, esse é um trabalho para você se sentir seguro, não para dar segurança. E sensação é diferente de fato.

Fora isso é o que o Bacco falou, é problema XY.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se eu compilar C, o arquivo de saída normalmente conterá a string se eu usar o comando `cat`.

Comment: @Asadefa Certo, mas o que o Maniero está a dizer é que mesmo com esse pequeno truque de avanços e recuos nos carateres asciis, alguém com um pouco mais de experiência em C e/ou assembly descobre a sua string num ápice. Conclusão: você acha que está seguro quando na verdade não está. Se isso era a password para aceder ao seu server, você já foi hackado.

Comment: @Asadefa o idioma da comunidade é nativamente português, o que significa "well it is not"?